# When I try o insert data dataexecuteQuery() isn't working?

Tags: java, mysql

Can't seem to fix this. Been trying to get it to work for the past hour. any help would be appreciated.

```
INFO: Server startup in 868 ms
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().Event{id=0, name='dads', venue='dasd', startDate='11/11/11', endDate='12/11/11'}
```

Seemed to be getting an error when I try to do an insert.

```
public void addEvent(Event event) throws DaoException{
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = this.getConnection();

            String query = "INSERT INTO TABLE EVENT VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)";         
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, event.getName());
            ps.setString(2, event.getVenue());
            ps.setString(3, event.getStartDate());
            ps.setString(4, event.getEndDate());

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(event.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    freeConnection(con);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new DaoException("Couldn't " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it looks like incorrect syntax of INSERT Query, update it likewise**

```
INSERT INTO EVENT VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?) // remove TABLE word
//INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES(...) , this is correct syntax.
```

**also correct here too**

```
    executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery()
// for insert/update/delete query always use executeUpdate(),
// for select query use executeQuery()
```

Comment: @vishalgajera  your second part is wrong. OP has to change the whole statement rs = ps.executeQuery();

Comment: @SpringLearner i think question owner able to understand what i try to tell him/her. anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for inserting or updating or deleting you should use [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())()

`executeUpdate()` returns `int` value

so replace this line `rs = ps.executeQuery();` with

```
int result = ps.executeUpdate();
```

**Note** you will get another error after modifying as per above because you sql query is also wrong

Use the following query

```
INSERT INTO EVENT VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE EVENT VALUES(null, 'dsad', 'dasdsa', '11/11/11', '12/11/11')' at line 1
Event{id=0, name='dsad', venue='dasdsa', startDate='11/11/11', endDate='12/11/11